# Filter the Gutenberg Block Editor controls

Tags: wordpress, editor, wordpress-gutenberg

eg: In the Gutenberg "Heading" block there is the option to set the level to "H2, H3, H4".
How (where) can i limit this list?

I only want to allow 'H3' for example

Looked everywhere on the internet. 
Filtering via 'registerBlockType' does not seem the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no API for that kind of filtering. The workaround is to hide panels or buttons with `display: none`. According to [this discussion](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/6023) on Github Wordpress 5.4 might solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There still doesn't seem to be a great solution to this particular thing yet, but you can essentially achieve the desired effect with something like this:

```
add_action('admin_head', function() {
  echo '<style>
  #editor .block-library-heading-level-toolbar button:nth-child(1),
  #editor .block-library-heading-level-toolbar button:nth-child(4),
  #editor .block-library-heading-level-toolbar button:nth-child(5),
  #editor .block-library-heading-level-toolbar button:nth-child(6) {
    display: none;
  }
  </style>';
});
```